# How to get paper.print() to work?

Tags: raphael

I have been trying to get the following Raphael code to just write something on the screen with no luck!

```
paper.print(30, 15, "TEXT", paper.getFont("Arial"), 20).attr({fill: "black"});
```

Is there anything else you need to do to get the text in the paper?!?!!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [cufonize](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/) a font, being sure to indicate that the cufonized font should register itself with Raphael, and include the resulting .js file before you can use getFont to retrieve it (there are no fonts available by default).  If you check, I'm reasonably sure you'll find that `paper.getFont("Arial")` is returning undefined.

Cufon essentially converts every glyph in a provided font into its vector equivalent -- Raphael simply transforms and sequences those paths to produce output.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I just thought some fonts would be available by default.